# How to add a new class to an existing class WP

Tags: jquery, wordpress

How can I add new class to an existing class in Wordpress? I turned on a wp login form plugin and there is some class assigned to it. I want add new one to it. Something like that:
From this

```
<input type="submit" ... ... class="button button-primary" ... >
```

To this

```
<input type="submit" ... ... class="button button-primary fw-btn fw-btn-black fw-btn-1" ... >
```

I tried to use a jQuery but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are couple of ways you can do this, but I think it's best you do it this way;

1. Install the 'String locator' plugin
2. Search for a string from the html code above e.g button button-primary
3. Check through the list of results displayed... Click on the result from your said plugin(in new tab)
4. Edit and Save